# How to store object of arrays in redis?

Tags: json, redis, ioredis

I have a json object structure like

```
{
  R10: [{ancestors: ['121', '122', '123']}, {ancestors: ['221', '222', '223']}, ...],
  R11: [{ancestors: ['1121', '1122', '1123']}, {ancestors: ['1221', '1222', '1223']}, ...],
  R12: [{ancestors: ['2121', '2122', '2123']}, {ancestors: ['2221', '2222', '2223']}, ...],
  .
  .
}
```

how to store it in redis for easy accesible. if i want to get ancestors of R10 and R11?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis has 2 modules that are included in the [redis-stack](https://redis.io/docs/stack/) package,

1. [RedisJSON](https://redis.io/docs/stack/json/) will let you store the JSON objects as JSONs, and
   perform JSON operations on them.
2. [RediSearch](https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/) will give you even more capabilities for querying
   your data and supports [indexing JSONs](https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/indexing_json/).

You can get a Redis-stack image from DockerHub, or follow the instructions from the documentation [here](https://redis.io/docs/stack/get-started/).

Here is a short example using the redis CLI

```
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET R10 $ '[{"ancestors": ["121", "122", "123"]}, {"ancestors": ["221", "222", "223"]}]'
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET R11 $ '[{"ancestors": ["1121", "1122", "1123"]}, {"ancestors": ["1221", "1222", "1223"]}]'
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET R12 $ '[{"ancestors": ["2121", "2122", "2123"]}, {"ancestors": ["2221", "2222", "2223"]}]'
OK
```

And then

```
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.GET R10 $.[0].ancestors
"[[\"121\",\"122\",\"123\"]]"

127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.GET R10 $.[*].ancestors
"[[\"121\",\"122\",\"123\"],[\"221\",\"222\",\"223\"]]"

127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.GET R10 $.[*].ancestors[*]
"[\"121\",\"122\",\"123\",\"221\",\"222\",\"223\"]"
```